# React - When I filter/map array objects, it doesn't show after clicking different date in the react-calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and practicing my basic knowledge such as setState, destructuring, etc by creating a simple todo-list app using react-calendar. I want to show a list of todo items specific to the date after clicking the specific date and adding todo items.

For example, when I click 28th Aug 2022 and add a todo item and click Add, the object appears at the bottom of the screen. Then I click 30th Aug 2022 to add another todo item for that date, which works fine (which means that particular todo item appears appears at the bottom of the screen). However, when I click 28th Aug 2022 again, the object I added previously doesn't show up again and same for when I click 30th Aug 2022, although I see the object array exists when I check console in Developer tool.

Am I missing an important concept?
Thank you very much in advance.

This is my App.jsx file:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Calendar from 'react-calendar';
import './calendar.css';
import Header from "./Header";
import CreateTodo from "./CreateTodo";
import EachItem from "./EachItem";


function App(){

    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
    date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
      
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
    
    const onChange = date => {setDate(date)};   
    
    

    function addTodo(content) {
        setTodos(previousTodos => {
        return [...previousTodos, {date, content}];
        
        });
    }


    function deleteTodo(id){
        setTodos(prevTodos => {
            return prevTodos.filter((todo, index) => {
                return index !== id;
            });
        });
    }

    return (
        <div>
      <Header />  
        <div className="app">
        <div className="calendar-container">
            <Calendar 
            onChange={onChange} 
            value={date}  

            />
           
        </div>
        <div className="text-center">
            {date.toDateString()}
        </div>
            <CreateTodo 
            onAdd={addTodo}
            date={date}
            />
        
            <div>
            <h1>Date specific items: </h1>
            {todos.filter(todo => todo.date === date)
                  .map((todo, index) => {
              
                return ( 
                    <EachItem 
                        key={index}
                        id={index}
                        content={todo.content}
                        onDelete={deleteTodo}
                        date={todo.date}
                    />
                );
            })}

            {console.log(todos)}
            {console.log("date is " + date )}
            

            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    
    );
}

export default App;
```

I added below 5 console.logs here:

```
 <h1>Date specific items: </h1>
        {todos.filter(todo => todo.date === date)
              .map((todo, index) => {

            console.log("todo is " + todo);
            console.log("todos is " + todos);
            console.log("todoItem.content is " + todo.content);
            console.log("todoItem.date is " + todo.date);
            console.log("date is " + date );
          
            return ( 
                <EachItem 
                    key={index}
                    id={index}
                    content={todo.content}
                    onDelete={deleteTodo}
                    date={todo.date}
                />
            );
        })}
```

Here are the results of console logs (In below example, I added a todo item on 29th, 30th, and 31st Aug.):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ulbh.png)

Here is the screenshot of the site to give you better idea. What happens is that there are currently 3 objects in the array of todos (one per 30st Aug, 31st Aug, and 1st Sep). When I click, e.g., 1st Sep and add "Test todo 3", it appears at the bottom of the screen ok. However, when I again click 31st Aug(I already added a "Test todo 2" for this date and it is one of the objects in the array), "Test todo 2" doesn't appear at the bottom of the screen even though the array has this object.
[Picture of the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0BGM.png)

Comment: Could you also post the results of your `console.log` calls here? My suspicion at this point is that probably the format of two dates - `date` and `todo.date` - don't mach.

Comment: I added console logs and the screenshot now. Thank you.

Comment: From your console logs, everything seems to work as intended. The `todos` list is getting updated every time. Why do you say newly added items are not rendered in the UI?

Comment: I added more description with the screenshot of the app. The problem is the all the todo items added into an array ok but when I click again the dates that I have added todo items they won't be displayed at the bototm of the screen even though the array has those items.